# TinyMCE: How to get paths in advimage to be relative

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, cmsmadesimple

I've already set `elements : 'relurls'` and it works for the main image.

But when i set an alternativ image with advimage for mouseover the path always remains absolute.

Is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are looking for this: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:relative_urls

a look to the FAQ section concering relativ paths might help too:
http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE_FAQ#Paths.2FURLs_are_incorrect.2C_I_want_absolute.2Frelative_URLs.3F

Comment: elements:'relurls',remove_script_host:true,relative_urls:true is set and still the mouseover images stay absolute

Comment: elements has no influence here: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:elements, can you create a tinymce fiddle?

Comment: i'm running tinymce on a cmsms system and can't get the configuration to work in a tinymce fiddle :S